# Angularjs issue - $http.get not working and changed into OPTIONS - Cross domain

Tags: angularjs, service, dependency-injection, cross-domain

I am a novice to Angularjs and tried to create a remote service (located on "http://dev.testmyserver2") for using in various applications (located on "http://dev.testmyserver").

This service retrieves various data about a user by using Colfusion and an Oracle database. It works perfectly when I launch the application directly in the browser. Nevertheless when I tried to call the function of this service (defined in the factory) from another application (thanks to a dependency called in the main module of this application), the http GET is modified in OPTIONS (visible in firebug) and I cannot retrieve the data (the status code of the http request is O). The function is correctly called (an alert "Function correctly called" or console.log from this function is correctly called), but no data of the person is retrieved.

I think that it's **a problem of Cross domain**. But I do not know how to solve it.

Here a little code:

**THE REMOTE SERVICE** with functions for retrieving data from a database:

- MODULE - appRemoteService.js:

  ```
  var app=angular.module('RemoteService', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);

  app.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, ngDialogProvider){

  // disable IE ajax request caching
  $httpProvider.defaults.cache = false;
  if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
      $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};
  }
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = '0';

  // Create the routes
  $routeProvider.when('/home',
  {
    templateUrl: 'template/allPersons.html',
    controller: 'ctrlPersons'

  })

  .when('/documentation',
  {
    templateUrl: 'template/documentation.html',
    controller: 'ctrlDocumentation'
  })      

  .otherwise({redirectTo:'/home'});  
  });    

  app.controller('ctrlPersons', function ($scope, FactoryRemoteService){
      FactoryRemoteService.getUserFromLogin("test").success(function(personInfo){
          alert(personInfo["VALUES"][0]["FIRSTNAME"]);
      });     
  });
  ```
- FACTORY - appFactoryRemoteService.js:

  ```
  app.factory('FactoryRemoteService', function($http){
  var factory={};
  factory.getUserFromLogin=function(uid){
      Alert("Function correctly called");
      return $http.get('http://dev.testmyserver2/myapp.cfc?method=getUserFromLogin&login=' + uid);
  };

  return factory; 
  })
  ```

**MY APPLICATION**:

- MAIN FILE - index.html:

  ```
      <title>My app</title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/bootstrap-3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/bootstrap-3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/select.css" rel="stylesheet">  

  </head>

  <body>

      <div class="container">
          <div class="spacer navbar">

              <h1 class="nav nav-pills navbar-left">MY APP</h1>

              <ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-right" data-ng-controller="NavbarController">
                  <li data-ng-class="{'active':getClass('/all-contacts')}"><a href="#/all-contacts">All contacts</a></li>
                  <li data-ng-class="{'active':getClass('/add-contacts')}"><a href="#/add-contacts">Add contacts</a></li>
              </ul>

          </div>

          <ng-view></ng-view>

    </div>

    <script src="lib/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/js/angular-route.min.js"></script>     
    <script src="lib/js/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>      

    <script src="lib/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js"></script>     

    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/appService.js"></script>

    <script src="http://dev.testmyserver2/app/appRemoteService.js"></script>
    <script src="http://dev.testmyserver2/app/appFactoryRemoteService.js"></script>     

  </body>
  ```
- MODULE - app.js:

  ```
  var app=angular.module('ContactsApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'RemoteService']);

  // register the interceptor as a service
  app.factory('HttpInterceptor', ['$q', '$rootScope', function($q, $rootScope) {
     return {
          // On request success
          request : function(config) {
          // Return the config or wrap it in a promise if blank.
          return config || $q.when(config);
      },

      // On request failure
      requestError : function(rejection) {
          //console.log(rejection); // Contains the data about the error on the request.  
          // Return the promise rejection.
          return $q.reject(rejection);
      },

      // On response success
      response : function(response) {
          //console.log(response); // Contains the data from the response.
          // Return the response or promise.
          return response || $q.when(response);
      },

      // On response failure
      responseError : function(rejection) {
          //console.log(rejection); // Contains the data about the error.
          //Check whether the intercept param is set in the config array. 
          //If the intercept param is missing or set to true, we display a modal containing the error
          if (typeof rejection.config.intercept === 'undefined' || rejection.config.intercept)
          {
              //emitting an event to draw a modal using angular bootstrap
              $rootScope.$emit('errorModal', rejection.data);
          }
          // Return the promise rejection.
          return $q.reject(rejection);
      }
  };
  }]);

  app.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider){
  // disable IE ajax request caching
  $httpProvider.defaults.cache = false;
  if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
      $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};
  }   
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = '0';

  // Add the interceptor to the $httpProvider to intercept http calls
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('HttpInterceptor');

  $routeProvider.when('/all-contacts',
  {
    templateUrl: 'template/allContacts.html',
    controller: 'ctrlContacts'

  })
  .when('/view-contacts/:contactId',
  {
    templateUrl: 'template/viewContact.html',
    controller: 'ctrlViewContacts'
  })
  .otherwise({redirectTo:'/all-contacts'});  

  });    


  app.controller('NavbarController', function($scope, $location){
  $scope.getClass=function(path){     
      if($location.path().substr(0,path.length) == path){
          return true;
      }else{
          return false;
      }       
  }
  });

  app.controller('ctrlViewContacts', function ($scope, $routeParams, RemoteServiceFactory){
  $scope.contact = null;

  // CALL OF THE REMOTE SERVICE
  RemoteServiceFactory.getUserFromLogin("test")
  .success(function(personInfo){
      alert(personInfo["VALUES"][0]["FIRSTNAME"]);
  })
  .error(function(personInfo, status){
      alert(status);
  }); 
  });
  ```

After several search on various forums I tested some solutions, but the problem is always present.

For instance I tried to add:

```
  //Enable cross domain calls
  $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;

  //Remove the header used to identify ajax call  that would prevent CORS from working
  delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

Or

```
  //Reset headers to avoid OPTIONS request (aka preflight)
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};
```

Could you please help me to find a solution to solve this problem?

Many thanks in advance for your reply

Comment: Does your service allow cross origin requests (cors)?  calling the service from the browser is different to the javascript.

Comment: I do not know how to see that. Besides it's not me who manage the server

Comment: First read about cors here http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing,  you should have a better understanding about what, why and how you add cors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For persons who encounter the same problem, I found a solution by using the [XDomain](https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain) third-party library. You have to implement a proxy.html file on the remote server where the service is located, and to call the file in a script tag in the main application.